# Swiper slider SVG icon doesn't show sometime in angular material svg icon

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, swiper.js

Swiper doesn't display SVG icons sometimes when I am using angular material SVG icon.

I am using svg icon this way - [Svg Icon Reference here](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-svg-icons-angular-material/)

#### HTML CODE

```
<swiper [config]="expertExperienceConfig">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="certificationProcess"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>CERTIFICATION PROCESS</h2>
                                <span>All your qualifications in one place</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="connectExperts"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>CONNECT WITH EXPERTS</h2>
                                <span>Talk to other users. Reach out and introduce yourself.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="linkRecruiters"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>DIRECT LINK TO RECRUITERS</h2>
                                <span>Share and be seen</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="blockchainVerification"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>BLOCKCHAIN VERIFICATION</h2>
                                <span>Trust, Validity, Convenience</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="planJourney"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>CERTIFICATION PROCESS</h2>
                                <span>All your qualifications in one place</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="swiper-slide__icon">
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="improveEfficiency"></mat-icon>
                            </div>

                            <div  class="swiper-slide__content">
                                <h2>CERTIFICATION PROCESS</h2>
                                <span>All your qualifications in one place</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next" hidden id="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev" hidden id="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                </swiper>
```

#### TYPE SCRIPT CODE(Configration code)

```
expertExperienceConfig: SwiperOptions = {
  loop: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 4,
  autoplay: 1000};
```

For more clarify, I just attached the image. So have a look, please Sometime icons show or sometimes not show.

I am using `Angular 6` and swiper `"swiper": "^3.4.2"` package this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the error, thank to this thread https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2629#issuecomment-737897281.

#### Solution

Add into your configuration the following

```js
private swiper: Swiper
isSwiperReady = false

expertExperienceConfig: SwiperOptions = {
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    navigation: true,
    on: { // <-- Fix the mat-icon error
      slideChangeTransitionStart: (swiper) => {
        if (!this.isSwiperReady) return

        let $wrapperEl = swiper.$wrapperEl
        let params = swiper.params
        $wrapperEl
          .children('.' + params.slideClass + '.' + params.slideDuplicateClass)
          .each(function () {
            let idx = this.getAttribute('data-swiper-slide-index')
            this.innerHTML = $wrapperEl
              .children(
                '.' +
                  params.slideClass +
                  '[data-swiper-slide-index="' +
                  idx +
                  '"]:not(.' +
                  params.slideDuplicateClass +
                  ')',
              )
              .html()
          })
      },

      slideChangeTransitionEnd: (swiper) => {
        if (!this.isSwiperReady) return

        swiper.slideToLoop(swiper.realIndex, 0, false)
      },
    },
};

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.swiper = new Swiper('.my-swiper-ref', expertExperienceConfig)
  this.isSwiperReady = true
}
```

#### Caution

- It's only required if you're using mat-icon with custom svg
- It will copy the DOM element and paste it as it would be the next one
- The `auto` option didn't worked for me
- `isSwiperReady` is used to fix firefox display error